# Batch program to rename and delete files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to check if there any files with *.del extension in c:\temp1 directory. If found, I need to rename such files to .done in the same x directory and delete the same file present in y directory but they will have .gz extension, please suggest. I am using the script below, but when I run it, it says file not found.

```
Inputfilename  : 20130216.001_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.del
Renamedfilename: 20130216.001_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.done 
Filetobedeleted: 20130216.001_visual_sciences_web_feed.out.gz
```

The script:

```
@echo off

set "dir=c:\raja\temp1"
set "ext=del"
set "rename=.done"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "%dir%\*.%extension%"^|sort /r') do (
    echo FILE: %%~fa
    call :rename "%%~fa"
)
pause
goto :eof
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("c:\raja\temp1\*.del") do (
    ren "%%~fa" *.done >nul 
    if exist "c:\temp2\%%~na.gz" del "c:\temp2\%%~na.gz" >nul 
)
```

For each file with .del extensions in source, rename to .done , and if file with same name and .gz extension exists (in temp2, from comments) , delete it

Comment: Thanks, but the files which i am going to delete is present in another directory ,say c:\temp2, how to refer this directory in this for loop

Comment: Updated answer to reflect directory change.